# What comes with the Pathfinder beginner box?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, pathfinder-beginner-box

I am about to order Pathfinder the beginner box off the internet. However, when I told my friend this he said he had to order everything separately. What all comes with the Beginner box for Pathfinder?

Comment: [Related] [Where do we go after Pathfinder Beginner Box?](http://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/27367/where-do-we-go-after-pathfinder-beginner-box) • [Summary of differences between Pathfinder Beginner Box and Core Rules?](http://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/19975/summary-of-differences-between-pathfinder-beginner-box-and-core-rules)

Answer (score 5):

**The Pathfinder RPG Beginner Box Includes**

- 64-page Hero's Handbook, detailing character creation, spells, equipment, and general rules for playing the game
- 96-page Game Master's Guide packed with adventures, monsters, magical
  treasures, and advice on how to narrate the game and control the
  challenges faced by the heroes
- A complete set of 7 high-impact polyhedral dice
- More than 80 full-color pawns depicting tons of heroes, monsters, and
  even a fearsome black dragon
- Four pregenerated character sheets to throw you right into the action
- Four blank character sheets to record the statistics and deeds of
  your custom-made hero
- A durable, reusable, double-sided Flip-Mat play surface that works
  with any kind of marker

[Source](http://paizo.com/pathfinderRPG/products/beginnerbox)

Comment: More specifically, it contains all you need to get started playing and running games - the other rulebooks are for later if you want to graduate to the more advanced game.